# How to substitute values in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

I'm working with excel and I want to count how many persons doing some sport or playing computer games. Is it possible? Let's assume that I have this table A:

```
Person  Activity
1       Football
2       Football
3       Football, FIFA 17
4       Hockey
5       Hockey
6       FIFA 17
7       FIFA 17
```

Now I used pivot table and I know that I can have these values:

```
FIFA 17
Football
Football, FIFA 17
Hockey
```

The first question is, could I use some if function for adding new column and translate it to category? By this table?

```
Activity            Category
FIFA 17             PC
Football            Sport
Football, FIFA 17   PC, Sport
Hockey              Sport
```

Something like :
if table A column activity is equal value from translation above, assign category. So I expect this result:

```
Person  Activity        Category
1   Football            Sport
2   Football            Sport
3   Football, FIFA 17   PC, Sport
4   Hockey              Sport
5   Hockey              Sport
6   FIFA 17             PC
7   FIFA 17             PC
```

And the final is that I want to count if column category contains one values from Sport, PC and if so the +1. So I expect the final result:

```
  Category    Count
  PC           3
  Sport        5
```

Bot steps (translation to category and containing of text) are really important. Because in general I will have to translate more values to one category. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the category column, then expand your PivotTable's range to include it. You can then switch around the structure to sum per category.

Comment: But it gives me sum of category "PC, Sport" as one category, but I want to count it in each category "PC", "Sport" not like one "PC, Sport"

Comment: I'd strongly suggest structuring your data with a row for Person 3 with Football and Sport, then another row for Person 3 with FIFA and PC, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
First to insert the category from the table of category use:
`=VLOOKUP(B2,$G$1:$H$4,2,FALSE)`
G1:H4 is the table with activity and category and keep $ for absolute reference
B2 is the Second column (activity column) where each person (Column A) has an activity
2 to return the second column value in Activity/Category Table
False to return the exact value
You can drag it down
For the Count use:
`=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$8,"*"&B11&"*")`
C2:C8 the new column of category created by the above formula
$ to have absolute reference
B11 is the Category which you want to count
"*"&... to include all combined category with the simple one

```
Column A  Column B         Column C  
Person    Activity          Category
1         Football          Sport  =VLOOKUP(B2,$G$1:$H$4,2,FALSE)
2         Football          Sport
3      Football, FIFA 17    PC, Sport
4         Hockey            Sport
5         Hockey            Sport
6         FIFA 17           PC
7         FIFA 17           PC  


        Column B    Column C
        Category    Count
            PC        3 =COUNTIF($C$2:$C$8,"*"&B11&"*")
            SPORT     5
```

Answer (score 0):

At the column B Select the all cell you want to fill with activity and "Define Name" to this range.(assume Activity).
Then Go to other cell where you want to display results. Define Name scope for whole sheet, you can display results any other sheet like sheet3 etc...ok.
Put this formula:
for football>> =countifs(Activity,"Football") Enter
repeat this an other cells for hockey, FIFA and other games